# ServiceStack : InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started

Tags: servicestack

Our API works fine, recently we changed from [ServiceStack 4.5.14](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/4.5.14) to [ServiceStack.Core 1.0.44](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Core/1.0.44) to take use of the powerful Kestrel http server.

An exception is thrown by the framework and caught by `AppHost.UncaughtExceptionHandlers`

```
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at ServiceStack.HttpExtensions.EndRequestWithNoContent(IResponse httpRes)
   at ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.WriteToResponse(IResponse httpRes, IRequest httpReq, Object result, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix, CancellationToken token)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.<>c__DisplayClass13_1.<ProcessRequestAsync>b__1(Object response)
   at ServiceStack.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.<ContinueClosure>b__0(Task innerTask)
```

1. This exception occurs after my method returns. It happens within the framework code.
2. Even when this error occurs, the API still response correctly.

**UPDATE**: After upgrading to ServiceStack.Core v5.0.2, it still occurs. However stacktrace is different.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at ServiceStack.HttpExtensions.EndRequestWithNoContent(IResponse httpRes)
   at ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.WriteToResponse(IResponse httpRes, IRequest httpReq, Object result, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix, CancellationToken token)
   at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.ServiceStackHandlerBase.<HandleResponseNext>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.ServiceStackHandlerBase.<HandleResponse>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Please confirm that the error still exists in the [latest ServiceStack v5](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.0.0) that's now on NuGet. Please note that [the .Core version of ServiceStack has merged into the main packages](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.0.0#v5-changes-and-migration-notes). If the issue still exists, you can send a stand-alone repro to https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues

Comment: It still happens in 5.0.2,  details are updated in question. I dont find the pattern to reprocedure it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Exception is prevented [by this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/636009ddee3c25f076f0a731243898e4846e7d09) from ServiceStack v5.0.3 that's [now available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).